# PartCover 4.0 Only Reports NUnit Libraries

Tags: .net-4.0, nunit, partcover

I'm using PartCover 4.0 (from [the sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/files/), latest dev build) with NUnit 2.5.8 on Windows 7 (x64). PartCover runs ok (using the -x86.exe), but it only shows me coverage for various NUnit packages -- not my own source-code.

I originally didn't use CorFlags.exe since I didn't get the COM error; I tried it anyways, and it didn't make any difference.

I've looked at all the other questions on Stack Overflow, and none seem to apply; I'm using PartCover 4.0, there are no spaces in any of my names, my coverage rule is the most broad (`+[*]*`), and I've run CorFlags.exe.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem yesterday and, searching for the answer, came across this unanswered question. Now that I've found the answer, at least for me, I thought I'd come and leave help for the next person to do the same.

It turned out to be as simple as NUnit-console.exe being configured to support .NET 2.0 rather than .NET 4.0. You can see this in a "Runtime Environment" section of the PartCover output.

In each of the config files in NUnit's `bin\net-2.0` folder, add this section directly below the configuration tag

```
<startup>
  <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506" />
</startup>
```